# i want to show accelerometer values for only 30s with flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I'm new in flutter and I want to know how i can have the measure of accelerometer just for a period of time.I really need help !
In fact Iwant to create an app that  can mesure the balance of a standing posture of a personne for 30 s with flutter.
Can you help me.thanks a lott

Comment: Did you try the package https://pub.dev/packages/sensors ?

Comment: yes sir ! i Try it and it Works .Thanh u